# Minkowski spacetime vs Euclidian space

Tags: special-relativity

Two questions marked in bold:

**What is the *magnitude* of a Minkowski spacetime four velocity?** I'm deducing that it is c for all observers, but I'd like it confirmed.

In Euclidian space, a velocity vector integrates over time to an absolute position.

**Does a four velocity integrate over time to a four dimensional displacement, and is it used in physics?**

Eventually; why not?

Comment: There are many kinds of four-vectors, and the magnitude of each type has a different interpretation. For example, energy-momentum is a four-vector, and its magnitude is the mass.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as if by *four vector* you are actually thinking of the [four velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity). The norm of the four velocity is indeed always $c$, and it does integrate to give a displacement along a world line.

The term *four vector* refers to anything that transforms as a vector, and as Ben notes in his comment this could refer to lots of different physical quantities that are unrelated to velocity.

Comment: Small comment: some people (notably Landau & Lifshitz, if I remember correctly) define the four velocity with norm $1$ instead of $c$.

Comment: Just a bit more on the world line. This implies that a distance can be calculated in terms of "world line distance" between two objects. Is that used for anything in physics? Why (not)?

Comment: @frodeborli: yes indeed, the distance calculated along the worldline this way is called the [line element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_element) or the [proper time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time). For a freely falling observer it's equal to the time shown on a clock carried by the observer. The line element is an invariant quantity in both SR and GR.

Comment: @frodeborli: "_that a distance can be calculated in terms of "world line distance" between two objects._" -- Not exactly. `1:` Two objects, $A$ and $B$, are characterized by a "_distance_" between each other only if and while they were **at rest** to each other (a.k.a. both having been members of the same inertial frame). If so then `2:` the value of the distance between objects $A$ and $B$ (at rest to each other) is $$\overline{AB} = \overline{BA} := \frac{c}{2} \tau_A^{\text{ping to B and back}} = \frac{c}{2} \tau_B^{\text{ping to A and back}}$$ where [... to be continued]

Comment: [contd. ...] where $A$'s ping duration $\tau_A^{\text{ping to B and back}}$ is the (constant) magnitude of any segment of $A$'s world line from any signal event in which $A$ took part until the corresponding event at which $A$ observed that $B$ had observed this signal event, $B$'s ping duration $\tau_B^{\text{ping to A and back}}$ is the (constant) magnitude of any segment of $B$'s world line from any signal event in which $B$ took part until the event at which $B$ observed that $A$ had observed this signal event, factor $\frac{1}{2}$ is conventional, and letter $c$ is a distinctive symbol.

Comment: @John Rennie: "_[...] proper time. For a freely falling observer it's equal to the time shown on a clock carried by the observer_" -- No, not in general. A clock does **not necessarily** show coordinate values $t$ whose differences are affine (proportional) to the duration (a.k.a. "_proper time_", or "magnitude of world line segment") of this clock (incl. the incidental observer "_carrying it_"). **Only if it does** it is called a **"good clock"**.

Comment: @user12262 strictly mathematically speaking, if you have absolute vales for each of the four components of the world line, of *both* objects - a distance can easily be calculated. My question is whether or not this distance is used anywhere in physics.

Comment: @frodeborli: "_if you have absolute values for each of the four components of the world line, of both objects - a distance can easily be calculated._" -- I'd like to see such a calculation in some detail. Are you perhaps considering to attribute a value of "_distance_" to a pair of object which are not at rest to each other ?? If so, that's (at best) called an "**improper** distance" between these two objects.

Comment: @user12262 The magnitude is simply |v1 - v2|. I don't understand that being at rest is relevant; a four vector is a reference to an absolute position in both time and space. Being *not at rest*, requires change to occur over time. By definition, a world line position is a particular moment in time.

Comment: @frodeborli: "_The magnitude is simply |v1 - v2|._" -- By "_v <index>_" do you mean to denote a four-vector? Four-vectors are referring to pairs of **events**, e.g. pair "{event _1_, origin event}", or pair "{event _2_, origin event}". Yes, their difference is again a four-vector (referring to pair "{event _1_, event _2_}"), and its magnitude may be evaluated. But in your comment `Sep 2 [2014] at 19:29` above you were discussing _"**objects**"_; as far as I understand, any "_object_" generally took part in **several** distinct events (which are timelike related to each other). So: which is it?

Comment: @user12262 By v<index> I mean to denote the absolute position of said particle/energy - i.e. relative to the big bang. I am aware that it is impossible to find the absolute value of such a vector. But if a four dimensional distance plays a part in curvature of space time, then i feel it explains cosmic red shift. The position would be the integrated position accumulated for each particle.

Comment: @frodeborli: Well, since you comment above seems to lead significantly beyond your OP question (as far as I understand it at all), I won't respond to it here in any detail. But at least: it is my impression that you should be capable of continuing to ask about what's of interest to you and/or to benefit from the Q&As which have been submitted here at PSE already.